# Simple RewriteRule not working as it should

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following couched in my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /properties/
RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)$ view.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

I want to write a "pretty" URL like http://example.com/properties/view/1 to http://example.com/properties/view.php?id=1.

The `RewriteRule` is passing the request to my `view.php` script, but it doesn't seem to be doing the query string bit. For example, if I do `print_r($_SERVER)` I see the following:

```
Array
(
    ...
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /Users/Martin/Sites/[removed]/
    ...
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /Users/Martin/Sites/[removed]/properties/view.php
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REQUEST_URI] => /properties/view/1
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /properties/view.php
    [PATH_INFO] => /1
    [PATH_TRANSLATED] => /Users/Martin/Sites/[removed]/1
    [PHP_SELF] => /properties/view.php/1
    ...
)
```

Why is `QUERY_STRING` empty? And why can't I access "1" with `$_GET['id']`?

**Note:** Obviously I've placed the `[removed]` tokens in the file paths.

Comment: The [RewriteRule for the QS](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString) seems correct. You shouldn't have to, but can try `[NC,L,QSA]` however. Does a `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` env variable show up possibly? Otherwise you might have to set up the `RewriteLog` to find out.

Comment: You're absolutely sure there's no other rules getting run first?

Comment: I've updated the OP with the entire contents of my `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Just an idea, but what if you add a `[R=302,L]`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look to me like your rewrite rule is working.  Otherwise I think the following values would be converted:

```
[REQUEST_URI] => /properties/view/1
[PHP_SELF] => /properties/view.php/1
```

If the rewrite rule were working, your php script would see the rewritten URI.

Some ideas...

What is your RewriteCond?  Is that matching?

I have never tried matching the partial path without trying to at least use a .* to match from the beginning.  What if you tried one of the following?

```
RewriteRule ^/?properties/view/([0-9]+)$ /properties/view.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*/view/([0-9]+)$ /properties/view.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I've updated the OP with the entire contents of my `.htaccess` file. There's no `RewriteCond`, but if it's not working then how is the URL ending up at `view.php`? I have no other `RewriteRule`s that would pass the URL /properties/view/1 to /properties/view.php?

Comment: Last time I used mod_rewrite, RewriteCond is necessary. This is what tells apache whether or not to run the RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

You are only rewriting urls that start with `view` using:

```
^view/([0-9]+)$
```

because the `^` means anchored to the start.

You could change it to for example:

```
^properties/view/([0-9]+)$
```

Comment: I've changed it once—by pasting the entire `.htaccess` file—for clarification?